# Problem with Neumann series

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $u\in\mathcal L(E,F)$ where $E$, $F$ and $G$ are three real Banach spaces such that $F$ is a proper subspace of $G$ and $E\subset F$. One knows that if $|||u|||=\max_{\substack{x\in E\\x\ne0_E}}\frac{||u(x)||_F}{||x||_E}<1\quad(*)$ (using Neumann series), then $\mathrm{Id_E}-u$ is invertible: in particular $(\mathrm{Id_E}-u)(E)=F$. My problem is: obviouly $u\in\mathcal L(E,F)$. Since the condition $(*)$ depends only on $E$, $\mathrm{Id_E}-u$ is invertible: in particular $(\mathrm{Id_E}-u)(E)=G$.

Something missed me but I do not know what....

Any enlight would be welcome.

Comment: $-u$ is $E \rightarrow G$ but $id_E$ is $E \rightarrow E$, you can’t add them!

Comment: Sorry. My post was terribly bad written. I edit it.

Comment: How do you define $u^2$ (and *a fortiori* Neumann series) if $u(E)$ isn’t a subset of the domain of $u$, which is $E$ itself?

Comment: For $u= \frac12 Id_E$ you would get that $\frac12 Id_E: E\to F$ is invertible, which is not true. Even if the compositions $u^n$ all make sense (which is equivalent to $u(E)\subseteq E$) then the von Neumann series _only_ tells you that $(Id_E - u) \cdot \sum_n u^n  = Id_E = \sum_n u^n \cdot (Id_E -u)$, which does not mean that $Id_E -u$ is invertible.